# Sorting MongoDB data in GraphQL resolver (Meteor/React/Apollo)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to sort some data returned by a query in GraphQl. I'm running a Meteor/React/Apollo/Graphql stack, and this line allows me to obtain all the data in my database in a resolver `resolvers.js` : `return database.find({})` I would like to sort it server-side by the "name" field and according to the docs and everything else I've been able to find online so far, `return database.find({}).sort({name:1})` should have cut it, but it's not actually returning anything and I can't seem to figure out why, nothing shows up in my console and no errors are being thrown, and hence I believe it's just null or empty.

In my Robo3T console I can run `database.find({}).sort({name:1})` and I can see the data actually being sorted. According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) I thought it may have been due to the [Node implementation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html), and so I tried `sort([["name",1]])` but that did not work either, and I'm not quite sure how else to go about this.

If there is no way to do this - should I just rely on client-side sorting? It's not many entries, < 100, and I think I should just sort it in the database itself because I never need the unsorted data and it's likely not even going to change much.

I would like to ask this regardless though, even if just sorting it once in my database is enough for this specific situation, how would I otherwise go about sorting data in a resolver, because I would need to do this in other instances?

Thanks!

EDIT - This is what I have:

```
export default {
    Query: {
        test_query(obj, args, context) {
            // Bottom line is output
            console.log("test1");
            console.log(Database.find({}).sort({name:1}));
            // Bottom line is not output
            console.log("test2");
            return Database.find({});
        },
}
```

EDIT2: My database is defined as `Database = new Mongo.Collection("db_name")`

Comment: @xadm Yeah I tried to log before return and there's nothing. No async/await. Do I need those? I updated the post with more code, to put it into context.

Comment: ah, native.... IDK, but log will help ;)

Comment: Could you share the code where `Database` is defined and initialized? Is it a meteor collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking at the wrong documentation. If this is indeed meteor, then `Database` is presumably a [meteor collection](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html), not a raw mongo collection. The interface on meteor collections is slightly different. In your case, I think you want:

```
Database.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}}).fetch();
```

Comment: This was it. I had declared my database as `Database = new Mongo.Collection("db_name")` but I was not aware it was treated differently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` returns a cursor:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find

This works for Meteor pubsub, but not for GraphQL/Apollo. Try `.find().toArray()`:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html#toArray

Comment: Thank you but this didn't really change anything unfortunately. When I try `console.log(Database.find({}).toArray)` it prints `undefined`. I've tried different combinations and orders of appending `.find(), .toArray, .sort()` all to no avail. It prints `undefined` or throws error messages saying they are not functions. I tried `toArray()` by the way - and it threw an error: `Database.find(...).toArray is not a function`. I had to remove the parentheses.